# Can't install ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot

Hey guys I am having trouble installing ubuntu on a lenovo b575 laptop. The installation goes fine but then on boot I just get a black screen. I have tried running boot-repair and get this output

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12011636/

Comment: Your output indicates that secure boot may be enabled. Does your Lenovo have secure boot and have you disabled it? I know Ubuntu (or Kubuntu in your case) should be able to handle it but it may be worth a try.

Comment: This bios has only basic settings. The only boot options are those relating to order.

Comment: Somebody on the Ubuntuforums appears to have got it working. See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117760&p=12532607#post12532607

Answer (score 0):

Does your laptop is using `UEFI` boot mode? If yes please disable UEFI (secure boot) from boot menu. Restart your laptop and press `BIOS` key (`F2 or F12` - depending on your hardware) and select `legacy boot`. Update in case of further issues.

Comment: I have read this on other posts but unfortunately the bios does not provide this option. I have looked to see if there was a bios update for this model but it doesn't seem like it. Is there a work around?